# Fat and protein breakdown

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, protein, fat

I know that after depletion of glycogen body starts to use fat for fuel. If I continue working an hour or more in this state, does my body start to use proteins for energy after a while? I have some belly fat so I don't think I am losing proteins from my muscles? Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On average, a person has more than 80,000 calories in fat storage.  You'd need to burn through this first before your body targets protein for fat storage.

Comment: Not to mention the 1500 calories of glycogen stored in your liver and muscles, which should last you a couple hours of exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about it, proteins start getting consumed only after prolonged periods of starvation when adipose tissues are depleted.  (Unless you are on a very low calorie diet.)